# Merge multiple ACF variables in one array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF relationship fields. I'm displaying multiple hand selected posts blocks. There is a last posts block where I want to exclude all the hand selected ones before.

How do I make an array of all ACF's to select them to exclude them from the loop?

This is my code so far (not working, it works if I only use one variable)

```
<?php   
$excluir = get_field('bloque_6_posts');
$excluir2 = get_field('bloque_2_posts');
$excluir3 = get_field('post_destacado');
$excluir4 = get_field('posts_destacados');
$excluir5 = get_field('bloque_4_posts');
$excluirtodo = array (
  $excluir,
  $excluir2,
  $excluir3,
  $excluir4,
  $excluir5
);
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 9,
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'post__not_in' => $excluirtodo
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

EDIT [SOLVED]: as @disinfor pointed on the comments the solution was array_merge instead of array

Comment: Are all your posts from the blog or do they include custom post types?

Comment: What are the values of `$excluir`, `$excluir2`,  `$excluir3`, etc?

Comment: @Xhynk OP said they are relationship fields - either Post Objects or Post IDs - that leads me to believe that the reason it works for one variable is because it's a single array vs trying to pass an array of arrays to `post__not_in`.

Comment: Juarez, try this `$excluirtodo = array_merge( $excluir, $excluir2, $excluir3 )` You are passing an array of arrays to the post__not_in..that won't work. With `array_merge()` you combine your arrays into one.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but wanted to see what the actual variables are

Comment: @disinfor thanks so much, array_merge did the trick. And yes, all of them were post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding my answer from the comments to help future visitors*

You are currently passing an array of arrays to the `post__not_in`. You need to use `array_merge` to combine the arrays into a single array.

```
<?php   
$excluir = get_field('bloque_6_posts');
$excluir2 = get_field('bloque_2_posts');
$excluir3 = get_field('post_destacado');
$excluir4 = get_field('posts_destacados');
$excluir5 = get_field('bloque_4_posts');

// NEW CODE HERE
$excluirtodo = array_merge(
  $excluir,
  $excluir2,
  $excluir3,
  $excluir4,
  $excluir5
);
// END ARRAY_MERGE
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 9,
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'post__not_in' => $excluirtodo
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a bad method to call 5 ACF fields and then combine them into an array at the time the page is built.
**For me, this method is better:**
1. Create a text AСF field - hide_excluir
2. Add filter in functions.php (When editing our page, all ACF fields with exceptions will be merged into an array and saved in the field that we created before).

```
add_filter('acf/save_post', 'excluir_post_filter', 20);
function excluir_post_filter($post_id) {

    if ( $post_id != 2 ) //Change to your page ID (or if you need use post type or page template, need modify)
        return;

    $excluir = get_field('bloque_6_posts');
    $excluir2 = get_field('bloque_2_posts');
    $excluir3 = get_field('post_destacado');
    $excluir4 = get_field('posts_destacados');
    $excluir5 = get_field('bloque_4_posts');

    $all_excluir = array_merge(
        $excluir,
        $excluir2,
        $excluir3,
        $excluir4,
        $excluir5
    );

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'hide_excluir', $all_excluir ); //Save array to our field

}
```

3. We use our field with get_post_meta

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 9,
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'post__not_in' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hide_excluir', true ) //Get our field with post array
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

*For testing methods, you can install the Query Monitor plugin and see the difference in the number of queries to the database.*